# Netbeans-J2ME (App not running)

Tags: netbeans, java-me

When I run any application in Netbeans then it is not running and close the program window appears..and the same version of Netbeans and same application runs perfectly fine on another PC. Do you have any solution for that? Please help me..Thanks in Advance..

Comment: if you are getting any errors, upload it.

Comment: Most Probably you are using lower version of java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check from both machines:

Java Runtime Environment

Netbeans settings and version

If all is the same it should work the same